# Set header in apache if it doesn't already exist

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, http-headers

I have a proxy that is injecting some headers but I want to modify it so it only sets the headers if they are not already present:

```
<Location /api>    
    RequestHeader set MY_HEADER "value"

    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
    ProxypassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
</Location>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Apache 2.4.7, x86_64, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I have found that this works

`RequestHeader   setIfEmpty      X-Forwarded-For     "127.0.0.1"`

works all day long. However if one tries to use a dynamic value,

`RequestHeader   setIfEmpty      X-Forwarded-For     "%{REMOTE_ADDR}e"`

does not work. I have found that you need the help of mod_rewrite to harvest the value. My configuration now looks like this, and it works.

`RewriteRule     .               -                   [E=noxff:%{REMOTE_ADDR}]
RequestHeader   setIfEmpty      X-Forwarded-For     "%{noxff}e"`

I know it is stoopid, but it works.

Answer (score 8):

How about something like:

```
RequestHeader set X-My-Header "value" expr="req('X-My-Header')==''"
```

Consult http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html for more info about the expr= syntax.

**Edit:** In Apache 2.2 you should be able to do this:

```
SetEnvIf X-My-Header "" no_my_header
RequestHeader set X-My-Header "value" env=no_my_header
```

Comment: I seem to be having some problems with that in apache 2.2.24.

Is it just a 2.4 thing?

Comment: Doesn't appear to exist in Apache 2.2.

Comment: See my edits above for Apache 2.2.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like "" as a regular expression but ^$ seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Apache 2.4.7

```
Header setifempty Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Apache 2.2.4 below

```
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin ""
Header edit Access-Control-Allow-Origin "^$" "*"
```

Comment: The solution for Apache 2.2.4 and below listed here `Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin ""` `Header edit Access-Control-Allow-Origin "^$" "*"` may have a side effect of appending `, ` to a non-empty header value because it's how `append` action works. It's the case, at least, in Apache 2.4.6.

Answer (score 2):

The following should be an equivalent to `RequestHeader setIfEmpty` in Apache versions <=2.4.6 (where `setIfEmpty` action is not supported):

```
RequestHeader set MY_HEADER "value" "expr=-z %{req:MY_HEADER}"
```