# Correct log format dependent on route

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, cdn, x-forwarded-for

I have a few virtual hosts running on a server, a couple are through a CDN and have `X-Forward-For` added to the headesr, sometimes it just goes through a load balancer where `RemoteIPHeader` is added.

I have 3 custom log configs:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" lb
```

and in my Virtual Host configs I use either lb, combined or proxy for the log format.

When I add `RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For` to set the client IP instead of load balancer IP, the lb log works correctly but the proxy one uses the LB IP. When I remove the `RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For` the proxy one has the client IP but the lb one has the load balancer IP. Which makes sense as I need to conditionally set `X-Forwarded-For` dependent on if it's already set by the CDN or not.

I've tried to do this like so:

```
<IfModule mod_headers>
    RequestHeader set X-Forward-For RemoteIPHeader expr="req('X-Forward-For')==''"
</IfModule>
```

[from this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/520477/set-header-in-apache-if-it-doesnt-already-exist) however it doesn't do anything. If do `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` it produces a syntax issue, if I put the above where I'm setting the log it says `RequestHeader set X-Forward-For RemoteIPHeader expr="req('X-Forward-For')==''"` has an unexpected $end.

How can set `X-Forward-For` correctly based on if it's set or not from the CDN?